# Rails routing per user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my rails app I have admins and users.

Users should only see their own resources /packages /warehouse /dashboard.
and admins should look into all of them with custom controllers /user1/packages /user2/packages and all of them at once (merged) with /packages /warehouse /dashboard

I'm not really sure how to get this structure into rails routes and controllers .

```
resources :users do
    resources :packages 

    collection do
        get 'warehouse' => "warehouse#index"
        get 'dashboard' => "dashboard#index"
    end
end
```

any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Role management with cancan and rolify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927570/role-management-with-cancan-and-rolify)

Comment: I know how to set the roles for my users, I'm struggling with the correct routing.

Comment: I don't think that you'd be able to define user specific routes, you can just restrict access of some users based on their roles to some routes.

Comment: I don't see a real benefit to trying to wedge in completely different routes per user type when you can just protect resources based on roles.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be trying to do this via routing but via permissions.

One simple way to do so would be using a `before_filter :check_permission` that checked the type of the user, like `current_user.is_a?(Admin)` and redirect to the proper page with the corresponding message (eg 'You are not allowed to access here.') if the checking resulted false.